# check if field exists or not mongodb node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a json data which is stored in mongodb. so when i parse thru url using node how to check if the data or field that already exists in db if not insert it. I am using mongodb node js driver to save data to db

example :

```
      {
       id :  "25"
       branch : "abc"
           {
             name : "xyz"
             email : 'xyz@abc.com'
            }
      }
```

so this is the json data i parse using node and store it in mongodb. what my question when i get same data again how to check in database if the field already exists in db or else insert it as a new field in collection

Comment: try the $exists operator

Comment: is this the way to use it db.collection.find({ "id": {$exists: true}}) then do nothing else insert or how to wrap this in a function ?

Comment: You cna do an update() statement with upsert and only upsert if that field does not exist

Comment: it's getting difficult to understand can give me an example link or any other how this could be done ?

Comment: like: `db.col.update({'id': {$exists: false}}, {'id': 1}, {upsert: true})` That will only insert so long as id does not exist

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Unique Index ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/ ) to ensure that you don't insert the same data twice.

If you want to update a document if it exists or if not create it: Look at the save method ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/ )

Comment: Note that if you have an array in the JSON structure the unqiue index will not work